# How to draw same image multiple times in a canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to code a simple JavaScript video game. I can load the background and player, and I'd like to draw an item multiple times. I use a class for player and this item with the canvas.drawImagemethod

In my infinite loop function I call a forEach to draw these images but just one appears on my canvas. How can I do this?

```js
const itemsData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 486, 486, 486, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
]

const CANVAS_WIDTH = 800;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;
const TILE_WIDTH = 12;
const TILE_HEIGHT = 12
const TILExROW = 67;
const MAP_ZOOM = 100; //percentage map has benn exported
const MAP_ZOOM_MULT = MAP_ZOOM / 100;
const TILE_COLLISION = 487;
const TILE_COLLECTOBJ = 486;
const MAP_OFFSET = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}
const PLAYER_IMG = {
  width: 288,
  height: 256,
  imgxRow: 12,
  imgxCol: 8,
  singleImg: {
    width: 21,
    height: 27
  },
  currentFrame: {
    horizontal: 3,
    vertical: 2
  }
}


const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.src = "https://imageshack.com/i/pmtPesL0p";

const playerImage = new Image();
playerImage.src = "https://imageshack.com/i/po1VURTCp";

const itemsImage = new Image();
itemsImage.src = "https://imageshack.com/i/potVaxoWp"


//class Sprite
class Sprite {
  constructor({
    position,
    image,
    frames = {
      currentH: 0,
      currentV: 0,
      maxH: 1,
      maxV: 1
    }
  }) {
    this.position = position;
    this.image = image;
    this.frames = { ...frames,
      elapsed: 0
    };

    this.image.onload = () => {
      this.width = this.image.width / this.frames.maxH;
      this.height = this.image.height / this.frames.maxV;
    }

    this.isMoving = false;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(
      this.image,
      this.frames.currentH * this.width,
      this.frames.currentV * this.height,
      this.image.width / this.frames.maxH,
      this.image.height / this.frames.maxV,
      this.position.x,
      this.position.y,
      this.image.width / this.frames.maxH,
      this.image.height / this.frames.maxV
    )

  }
}


const background = new Sprite({
  position: {
    x: MAP_OFFSET.x,
    y: MAP_OFFSET.y
  },
  image: bgImage
});

const player = new Sprite({
  position: {
    x: canvas.width / 2 - (PLAYER_IMG.width / PLAYER_IMG.imgxRow / 2),
    y: canvas.height / 2 - (PLAYER_IMG.height / PLAYER_IMG.imgxCol / 2)
  },
  image: playerImage,
  frames: {
    currentH: PLAYER_IMG.currentFrame.horizontal,
    currentV: PLAYER_IMG.currentFrame.vertical,
    maxH: PLAYER_IMG.imgxRow,
    maxV: PLAYER_IMG.imgxCol
  }
});



//items map
const itemsMap = [];
for (let i = 0; i < itemsData.length; i += TILExROW) {
  itemsMap.push(itemsData.slice(i, TILExROW + i));
}

const items = [];

itemsMap.forEach((row, i) => {
  row.forEach((tile, j) => {
    if (tile === TILE_COLLECTOBJ) {
      items.push(new Sprite({
        position: {
          x: j * TILE_WIDTH * MAP_ZOOM_MULT + MAP_OFFSET.x,
          y: i * TILE_HEIGHT * MAP_ZOOM_MULT + MAP_OFFSET.y
        },
        image: itemsImage,
        frames: {
          currentH: 0,
          currentV: 0,
          maxH: 4,
          maxV: 1
        }
      }))
    }
  })
});


//refres canvas image seamlessly
async function animate() {

  //draw the background
  background.draw();



  items.forEach(item => {
    item.isMoving = true;
    item.draw();
  });

  //draw the player
  player.draw();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
animate();
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Now it works. As you can see there's jus an heart image on the top of the map, while they should be 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your three hearts - which are instances of the `Sprite()` class - share the same instance of an `Image` object.

In the constructor of the `Sprite` class, you've added an onload listener:

```
this.image.onload = () => {
    this.width = this.image.width / this.frames.maxH;
    this.height = this.image.height / this.frames.maxV;
}
```

unfortunately this listener will just fire once - as it's the same image for all three Sprite instances. That means it's `width` and `height` properties won't ever get populated and ultimately causing an error in the sprite's `draw()` function as the width and height is undefined.

You can fix that by adding a `loaded` property to the image objects as the onload event fires and query this property inside the draw function. If it's true, read the width & height from the image object.

Here's your modified code:

```js
const itemsData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 486, 486, 486, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
]

const CANVAS_WIDTH = 800;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;
const TILE_WIDTH = 12;
const TILE_HEIGHT = 12
const TILExROW = 67;
const MAP_ZOOM = 100; //percentage map has benn exported
const MAP_ZOOM_MULT = MAP_ZOOM / 100;
const TILE_COLLISION = 487;
const TILE_COLLECTOBJ = 486;
const MAP_OFFSET = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}
const PLAYER_IMG = {
  width: 288,
  height: 256,
  imgxRow: 12,
  imgxCol: 8,
  singleImg: {
    width: 21,
    height: 27
  },
  currentFrame: {
    horizontal: 3,
    vertical: 2
  }
}


const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.src = "https://imageshack.com/i/pmtPesL0p";

const playerImage = new Image();
playerImage.src = "https://imageshack.com/i/po1VURTCp";

const itemsImage = new Image();
itemsImage.src = "https://imageshack.com/i/potVaxoWp"


//class Sprite
class Sprite {
  constructor({
    position,
    image,
    frames = {
      currentH: 0,
      currentV: 0,
      maxH: 1,
      maxV: 1
    }
  }) {
    this.position = position;
    this.image = image;
    this.frames = {
      ...frames,
      elapsed: 0
    };

    this.image.onload = () => {
      this.width = this.image.width / this.frames.maxH;
      this.height = this.image.height / this.frames.maxV;
      this.image.loaded = true;
    }


    this.isMoving = false;
  }

  draw() {
    if (this.image.loaded) {
      this.width = this.image.width / this.frames.maxH;
      this.height = this.image.height / this.frames.maxV;
    }

    ctx.drawImage(
      this.image,
      this.frames.currentH * this.width,
      this.frames.currentV * this.height,
      this.image.width / this.frames.maxH,
      this.image.height / this.frames.maxV,
      this.position.x,
      this.position.y,
      this.image.width / this.frames.maxH,
      this.image.height / this.frames.maxV
    )

  }
}


const background = new Sprite({
  position: {
    x: MAP_OFFSET.x,
    y: MAP_OFFSET.y
  },
  image: bgImage
});

const player = new Sprite({
  position: {
    x: canvas.width / 2 - (PLAYER_IMG.width / PLAYER_IMG.imgxRow / 2),
    y: canvas.height / 2 - (PLAYER_IMG.height / PLAYER_IMG.imgxCol / 2)
  },
  image: playerImage,
  frames: {
    currentH: PLAYER_IMG.currentFrame.horizontal,
    currentV: PLAYER_IMG.currentFrame.vertical,
    maxH: PLAYER_IMG.imgxRow,
    maxV: PLAYER_IMG.imgxCol
  }
});



//items map
const itemsMap = [];
for (let i = 0; i < itemsData.length; i += TILExROW) {
  itemsMap.push(itemsData.slice(i, TILExROW + i));
}

const items = [];

itemsMap.forEach((row, i) => {
  row.forEach((tile, j) => {
    if (tile === TILE_COLLECTOBJ) {
      items.push(new Sprite({
        position: {
          x: j * TILE_WIDTH * MAP_ZOOM_MULT + MAP_OFFSET.x,
          y: i * TILE_HEIGHT * MAP_ZOOM_MULT + MAP_OFFSET.y
        },
        image: itemsImage,
        frames: {
          currentH: 0,
          currentV: 0,
          maxH: 4,
          maxV: 1
        }
      }))
    }
  })
});


//refres canvas image seamlessly
async function animate() {

  //draw the background
  background.draw();

  items.forEach(item => {
    item.isMoving = true;
    item.draw();
  });

  //draw the player
  player.draw();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```